# How to schedule creating a new collection in firebase

Tags: firebase

I want to limit every collection records by 30, so when a collection had 30 records, firebase automatically creates a new collection with new records.

Comment: There is nothing built into Firebase to do this. Since the collection that you write to is identified in your code, you will have to update your code to write to the new collection.

Comment: So I have to use a backend?

Comment: Firestore is a backend database and you are creating an app to interact with it. You code could know if a collection has 30 documents either by counting them or better yet, keep an counter that is incremented when a document is added. It should be pretty straightforward. Is there more to the question as it's pretty broad as is.

Comment: You can do this in the front-end or in the back-end code, but *you* will have to write code for it, as this is not a built-in operator.